# Why is /boot so small?

Tags: kernel, disk-usage, boot-partition

I recently had the warning that `/boot` was running out of space and I found [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot). Having rebooted and confirmed that I didn't fubar my system, I'm looking at **why it happened in the first place?**

Okay so evidently there were a lot of kernels installed. That's not something I did manually (I don't even know what a kernel *is!*) so I guess there's an automatic update process that keeps my system in ship shape. I'm fine with that.

Looking at the `Disks` utility I see that **the `/boot` partition is only 255MB** out of my 128GB SSD. Again, I didn't configure this - it must be the default setting of the Ubuntu installer.

--> Why isn't the /boot partition bigger by default? It seems silly to create a partition that's less than 2% of the drive size. I know that increasing the partition would merely postpone the problem, so perhalps I should really be asking: **Why can't Ubuntu solve this problem automatically?** All it would need was to keep track of which kernels haven't been used for a long time, and auto-remove those?

Comment: Who installed Ubuntu? Is your home partition encrypted?

Comment: @Pilot6 I installed Ubuntu myself, using the friendly non-geek installer, and didn't select encryption. There's a 128GB SSD for the OS and a 3TB HDD for /home.

Answer (score 2):

### Okay, what is a kernel?

> In computing, the kernel is a computer program that manages I/O requests from software, and translates them into data processing instructions for the central processing unit and other electronic components of a computer. The kernel is a fundamental part of a modern computer's operating system.

[image]

[Source, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28operating_system%29)

### When does this update?

I think it is lumped in with the Ubuntu Base updates:

[image]

> The base package is (a) `ubuntu-desktop` if it is installed, otherwise (b) the alphabetically first of any of the metapackages that are installed, for example, `kubuntu-desktop` or `lubuntu-desktop`.

It also seems to have the kernel as part of it - but of course there aren't always kernel updates.

It is normally the kernel that needs the restart when you update (although from 4.0+ it wont).

[Source, Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareUpdates#Expanded_presentation_of_updates)

Now to your main question.

I have 6 kernels installed at the moment:

```
linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic
linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic
linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic
linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic
linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic
```

You can find out with this command:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

### Why doesn't ubuntu just remove them?

Well, I sometimes use a different kernel. For example, in the current one I have, `linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic`, there is a strange bug I got when I broke my `xorg.conf` file - I couldn't access tty easily. `linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic` fixed this for me, so I could undo my meddlings.

This is the same for lots of people - Ubuntu isn't in the business to remove packages you might need (even if you haven't used it for years, you may want it). I *could* do something different, with asking if it needs removing, but it doesn't.

### Why is `/boot` so small?

Why does it need to be big? My current kernel is 5.6 MB:

```
-rw-------  1 root root 5.6M May 20 12:11 vmlinuz-3.13.0-53-generic
```

And the total "stuff" for the `-53` version is 37.1 MB. You can fit 4 kernels in there, normally enough.

Also, note that [the recommended size for `/boot` is now 500-600 MB](https://serverfault.com/a/334665).

### Do I need it?

You don't - I don't have it. It's not compulsory, but there are some advantages:

- as a rescue partition
- rootfs is on a LVM, RAID, is encrypted, or unsupported by GRUB
- maybe saves a few seconds of boot time

[Source, Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/334669/253429)

Comment: What is the relation between ubuntu-desktop and kernel?

Comment: @Pilot6 do the kernel updates not come in Ubuntu Base?

Comment: What do you mean? What is Ubuntu Base? Kernels are not related with DE at all.

Comment: @Pilot6 the updates you see called Ubuntu Base, do they not contain Kernel updates?

Comment: I never met such term "Ubuntu Base". Kernel updates come from <release_name>-updates of "main" repository. My point that there are no dependencies between ubuntu-desktop and any kernel packages.

Comment: So kernels do not "base" on desktop environment in any way.

Comment: I see your screenshot, but that does not change anything. There is no relation between "Ubuntu Base" group of updates with an ubuntu-desktop meta package. It looks like updates are grouped some way.

Comment: @Pilot6 yes, I know they're grouped. I *think* that kernel updates are put in with past updates - in that category. Do you think they stand alone?

Comment: I do not care of categories in that updater. They mean almost nothing. They are done just not to confuse people. So I suggest removing "ubuntu-desktop" from the great answer just not to look stupid.

Comment: @Pilot6 I think it links, I got the info from the wiki.

Comment: Thank you for the educational background, that was helpful! So it would seem I chose to use LVM when I installed my system - I don't know, can't remember (and I'm not at the machine now so I can't look it up). Would it make sense to back up everything and reinstall from scratch?

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun not really, I'd just leave it. Just make sure you clean away the kernels reasonably often.

Comment: Very curious. Recommended, is 500Mb, default is 250Mb, my freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04 has run out of /boot space in 2 months.  Not good at all. Am considering a reinstall.

Comment: @PhilLord sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: @Tim I know how to remove the kernels, but every 2 months? If I go back and repartion with a Gb, it was last several years. I cannot understand why the default is so slow, and wished I noticed it earlier.

Comment: @PhilLord Because more is wasting the space - you can just run a command slightly more often. I run it every time I `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: @Tim Turns out that this has been reported as a bug and fixed. Sadly, for those of us already here, it means a /boot resize.  Unfortunate. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1465050